# Flow divs into screen

Tags: jquery, css

i need to manage below screen with div based on detected screen (flow)

i have try with flot:left and clear property of div not able to get what i want.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Need more info. What have you tried? jsFiddle? Any code? Anything at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to take all the of the pain out of creating a complex layout like this is to employ some kind of css framework that uses a grid system and supports a responsive layout.

Most importantly, if you choose a good framework, they will have worked out all the weird cross-browser issues you're going to come up against when trying to produce a responsive design like this.

The above example you give would be relatively straightforward to produce with [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/).  I would recommend investigating this.